# Java compilation failed during syntax definition using rascalMPL due to code too large

Tags: rascal

I keep getting a "Java compilation failed due to code too large" error when I try to parse my grammar. I am trying to implement an sql grammar and have looked through my syntax definition and I don't know what I did wrong. What could be causing this error?

[Compilation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws7y9.png)

I tried commenting out some code and it works fine when I do. I also looked at the layout definition and everything looks fine.

Comment: That's quite a surprise! It can happen if the generated JVM bytecode by the Java compiler that compiles the Java code that is generated for the parser is too big somehow. Typically a method would be too big then, which corresponds to a single alternative rule in the grammar. Do you know which rule could be so big?

Comment: It's not a problem of grammar size, I would guess. Only rule size. If you find a cause, please submit an issue at http://github.com/usethesource/rascal/issues ? thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your reply @JurgenVinju
I am still experiencing the issue and I can't seem to figure out which rule is so big. 
I have submitted an issue at https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/issues/1924

Comment: ok that's great; we can continue there.